# R - find a max value in r

Tags: r

I am studying about R and i have data like this

```
Name    daysubmit    score
 A      01/02/2016
 B      7/02/2016
 A      11/02/2016
 A      20/02/2016
 B      21/02/2016
 B      01/03/2016
 ...
```

In this table, "daysubmit" sorted by day

I want to find the max time of 2 submission of each people

Thanks.

Comment: `aggregate(Name ~ daysubmit, df, max)`

Comment: @waterling Looks like `daysubmit` is still character.

Comment: Please, read [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/3817004). In particular, please [edit] your question and add a `dput` of your date frame. Furthermore, please, show what the expected result should look like. Thank you.